# Android SDK: Way to check for broken/corrupt packages?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, checksum

**BACKGROUND:**

I'm troubleshooting in Eclipse and am having a lot of problems getting it to load default Wizard created Android Apps with the correct target API installed. In reinstalling Android SDK packages, I ran into a package that wouldn't install but still appeared to. In another instance, three of my packages from my Extra folder happened to show up as broken. I'll try and unload/load all the packages again, but it made me wonder....

**QUESTION:**

***Is there a way to manually check the Android SDK packages to see if they are corrupted? Option/program/checksum?***

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is a [MD5 checksum](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) generated for each Android SDK package, but not for installed files and folders from the Android SDK package.